# Verilog int unsigned VHDL equivalent

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I would like to access a Verilog module within VHDL. Among others, the Verilog module has the input parameter:

```
parameter int unsigned RST_CYC = 100_000;
```

Is the following the correct VHDL equivalent for mapping?

```
constant RST_CYC : unsigned := d"100_000";
```

Comment: IIRC, Verilog ints are 32 bits. d"100_000" is only 17 bits. But inter-language connection is not standardised and tool dependent, so whether it connects is up to the tool. If you are just looking for a direct equivalent without connecting the two, then VHDL's `integer` type may be more appropriate.

Comment: But when I use `integer` I get the error, that I try to map an `integer` to a `unsigned`. The goal is to map the VHDL variable to the Verilog module.

Comment: This is a tool problem, not a language problem. If it wont accept unsigned, then you will likely need to use `std_logic_vector`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend sticking with integers (or naturals, which are integers that can't go negative). So in this case:

```
constant RST_CYC : natural := 100000;
```

Declaring a signal would look like this:

```
signal rst_count : integer range 0 to RST_CYC;
```

Stick with integers if you can. If you NEED to convert to `unsigned` or `std_logic_vector` then you can do something like:

```
unsigned_val <= to_unsigned(rst_count, unsigned_val'length);
```